# Instance method overiding vs Field hiding

Tags: java, overriding, member-hiding

Below is the code,

```
package ClassesOverridingHidingAccess;

interface I{
    int x = 0;
}
class T1 implements I{
    int x = 1;
    String s(){
        return "1";
    }
}

class T2 extends T1{
    int x  = 2;
    String s(){
        return "2";
    }
}

class T3 extends T2{
    int x = 3;
    String s(){
        return "3";
    }

    void test(){
        // Accessing instanc method
        System.out.println("s()=\t\t" + s());   // 3
        System.out.println("super.s()=\t" + super.s()); // 2
        System.out.println("((T2)this).s()= " + ((T2)this).s());  // 3; method is resolved at runtime
        System.out.println("((T1)this).s()= " + ((T1)this).s());  // 3; method is resolved at runtime

        //Accessing instance attribute
        System.out.println("\n\nx=\t\t" + x);  // 3
        System.out.println("super.x=\t" + super.x);  // 2
        System.out.println("((T2)this).x=\t" + ((T2)this).x);  // 2; resolved at compile time
        System.out.println("((T1)this).x=\t" + ((T1)this).x);  // 1; resolved at compile time
        System.out.println("((I)this).x=\t" + ((I)this).x);   // 0; resolved at compile time
    }
}

public class SuperAndInstanceMethods {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new T3()).test();
    }
}
```

where,

it is the run time class, which counts in case of instance method access.

it is the view of an object, which counts in case of field access.

Casting does not change object's class type. I mean `((T1)this) instanceof T3` is `true`, if `this` points to object of type `T3`.

So, What is the rationale behind the rule followed for field access? Rule for instance methods make sense to me.

*Note: For me, it is an overhead to remember these rules unless there is a proper reason.*

Comment: there is no field overriding, only `hiding`

Comment: @Hacketo OK. I re-corrected the query. am new to this terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance Method's are resolved via a [V-table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), that is how the runtime type's method are invoked. There is no such table enabling this for fields (or static methods for that matter), so the compile time type is used.

Hiding fields and then doing this kind of stuff `((T1)this).x` is very unusual, I would avoid it as I don't think it's readable.

And the [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html) confirms:

> Within a class, a field that has the same name as a field in the superclass hides the superclass's field, even if their types are different. Within the subclass, the field in the superclass cannot be referenced by its simple name. Instead, the field must be accessed through super, which is covered in the next section. **Generally speaking, we don't recommend hiding fields as it makes code difficult to read.**

(Emphasis mine)

So it should be low on your list of rules to remember.

You can turn on a error/warning for this in all good IDE's, here it is in IntelliJ:

[image: IntelliJ inspection]

Comment: I think you should say instance methods are resolved via V-TABLE. static methods are resolved at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Just Keep the Thumb Rule as :

1. In case of Method Overriding the reference variable does not matter but what matters is the actual object type which this variable is referring to.
2. In case of Variable Shadowing/Field Hiding, the reference variable matters while the actual object type which this variable is referring to, does not matter.

Consider the below example for refrence :

```
public class Parent {
    String name = "Parent";
    public void printName(){
    System.out.println("Parent Method");
  }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
  String name = "Child";
  public void printName(){
    System.out.println("Child Method");
   }
}
```

Now will run this `main()` method in **Test Class** :-

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Parent p = new Parent();
    Child c = new Child();

    System.out.println(p.name); // will print Parent's name
    System.out.println(p.printName());// will call Parent
    System.out.println(c.name); // will print Child's name
    System.out.println(c.printName());// will call Child

    Parent pc = new Child();
    System.out.println(pc.name);// will print Parent's name
    System.out.println(pc.printName());// will call Child
   }
}
```

This will print the below in Accordance to the rules , which I stated above :-

```
Parent 
Parent Method
Child
Child Method
Parent
Child Method
```